# Let $[x]$ denote the greatest integer function. Find the value of $\int_0^{n^{\frac1k}}[x^k+n]dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $[x]$ denote the greatest integer function. Then the value of $\int_0^{n^{\frac1k}}[x^k+n]dx$  equals

A.   $\displaystyle n^2+\sum_{i=0}^ni^{\frac 1k} $

B.   $\displaystyle 2n^{\frac {1+k}{k}}-\sum_{i=0}^n i^{\frac 1k}$

C.   $\displaystyle 2n^{\frac {1+k}{k}}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^{\frac 1k}$

D.None of these

I tried to simplify $\displaystyle \int_0^{n^{\frac1k}}[x^k+n]dx$ by writing this as $$\int_0^{n^{\frac1k}}([x^k]+n)dx=\int_0^{n^{\frac 1k}}[x^k] +\int_0^{n^{\frac 1k}}n=\int_0^{n^{\frac 1k}}[x^k]+n.n^{\frac 1k}=\int_0^{n^{\frac 1k}}[x^k]+n^{\frac {1+k}{k}}.$$  One observation is that $[x^k]=0$ if $0\leq x<1$ and also $[x^k]=1$ if $1^{\frac 1k}\leq x<2^{\frac 1k}, $ holds as well if $k\in\Bbb N.$ Continuing the assumption that $k\in\Bbb N$ we have $[x^k]=2$ if  $2^{\frac 1k}\leq x<3^{\frac 1k},$ and so on. I thought this observation might be helpful here. So, if we write,  $\displaystyle \int_0^{n^{\frac 1k}}[x^k]$ as $\displaystyle \int_0^{n^{\frac 1k}}[x^k]=\int_0^{1^{\frac 1k}}[x^k]+\int_{1^{\frac 1k}}^{{2^{\frac 1k}}}[x^k]+...+\int_{(n-1)^{\frac 1k}}^{n^{\frac 1k}}[x^k].$ If we now, simplify this down, as $$\int_{0}^{{n^{\frac 1k}}}[x^k]=\int_0^{{1^{\frac 1k}}}[x^k]+\int_{1^{{\frac 1k}}}^{{2^{\frac 1k}}}[x^k]+...+\int_{(n-1)^{\frac 1k}}^{{n^{\frac 1k}}}[x^k]=0+1(2^{\frac 1k}-1^{\frac 1k})+2(3^{\frac 1k}-2^{\frac 1k})+...+(n-1)(n^{\frac 1k}-(n-1)^{\frac {1}{k}})=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(i)((i+1)^{\frac {1}{k}}-i^{\frac 1k}).$$ So, we can say, $\displaystyle \int_0^{n^{\frac1k}}[x^k+n]dx$  equals $\displaystyle n^{\frac {1+k}{k}}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(i)((i+1)^{\frac {1}{k}}-i^{\frac 1k})=n^{\frac {1+k}{k}}+(-1^{\frac 1k} -2^{\frac 1k} -...-(n-1)^{\frac 1k})=n^{\frac {1+k}{k}}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^{\frac 1k}=n^{\frac {1+k}{k}}+n^{\frac 1k}-\sum_{i=0}^ni^{\frac 1k}.$

But unfortunately, the final result is not matching with any of the  given options. caan anyone please explain where is the flaw in my approach (if there is any) ?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E%7Bn%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%7D%7D%7D%5Clfloor%20x%5Ek%2Bn%5Crfloor%20dx%24&p=3), there's the AoPS threads [ST11__#12](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1249345p6425759) and [About kth derivatives of a polynomial](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2087134p15057706).

Comment: Set $x=3/2\in[1,2)$. Then $x^2=9/4$ so $[x^2]=2$ Your assumption does not hold for all $k$, so your subsequent work is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lfloor x^k + n \rfloor = \lfloor x^k \rfloor + n$$ and with the substitution $$u = x^k, \quad x = u^{1/k}, \quad dx = \frac{1}{k} u^{1/k-1} \, du$$ it follows that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{x=0}^{n^{1/k}} \lfloor x^k + n \rfloor \, dx 
&= \int_{x=0}^{n^{1/k}} \lfloor x^k \rfloor \, dx + n^{1/k + 1} \\
&= \int_{u=0}^n \lfloor u \rfloor \frac{1}{k} u^{1/k-1} \, du + n^{1/k + 1} \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} m \int_{u=m}^{m+1} \frac{1}{k} u^{1/k-1} \, du + n^{1/k+1} \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} m \Bigl[ u^{1/k} \Bigr]_{u=m}^{m+1} + n^{1/k + 1} \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} m \left((m+1)^{1/k} - m^{1/k}\right) + n^{1/k + 1} \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \left( (m+1)^{1/k + 1} - m^{1/k + 1} \right) - \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} (m+1)^{1/k} + n^{1/k + 1} \\
&= n^{1/k + 1} - 0^{1/k+1} - \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} (m+1)^{1/k} + n^{1/k + 1} \\
&= 2n^{1/k + 1} - \sum_{i=1}^n i^{1/k}.
\end{align}$$

This is equivalent to answer choice (B).

---

The error in your solution is here:

> One observation is that $\lfloor x^k \rfloor = 0$ if $0 \le x < 1$ and also $\lfloor x^k \rfloor = 1$ if $1 \le x < 2$, holds as well if $k \in \mathbb N$. Continuing the assumption that $k \in \mathbb N$ we have $\lfloor x^k \rfloor = 2$ if $2 \le x < 3$, and so on.

This is clearly false as stated in the comments.  For $\lfloor x^k \rfloor = m$ for some nonnegative integer $m$, we require $m \le x^k < m+1$, hence $$m^{1/k} \le x < (m+1)^{1/k}.$$  So this partitions the interval of integration as follows:
$$[0,\infty) = [0, 1) \cup [1, 2^{1/k}) \cup [2^{1/k}, 3^{1/k}) \cup [3^{1/k}, 4^{1/k}) \cup \cdots$$ and not $$[0,\infty) = [0, 1) \cup [1,2) \cup [2,3) \cup \cdots.$$

Until this error is corrected, there is no purpose in checking your computation further, because all of the subsequent calculations depend on applying the correct partition.

---

The next issue in your solution begins at
$$\int_{x=0}^{1^{1/k}} \lfloor x^k \rfloor \, dx + \int_{x=1^{1/k}}^{2^{1/k}} \lfloor x^k \rfloor \, dx + \cdots + \int_{x=(n-1)^{1/k}}^{n^{1/k}} \lfloor x^k \rfloor \, dx \\
\quad = 0 + 1(2^{1/k} - 1^{1/k}) + 2(2^{3/k} - 2^{2/k}) + \cdots + n(n^{n/k} - (n-1)^{(n-1)/k}).$$
This is not a correct evaluation of the integrals on each subinterval.  Instead, for a general nonnegative integer $m \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$, we simply have
$$\int_{x=m^{1/k}}^{(m+1)^{1/k}} \lfloor x^k \rfloor \, dx = m \int_{x=m^{1/k}}^{(m+1)^{1/k}} \, dx = m \left((m+1)^{1/k} - m^{1/k}\right)$$ after using the aforementioned fact that $\lfloor x^k \rfloor = m$ when $m^{1/k} \le x < (m+1)^{1/k}$.  Consequently
$$\int_{x=0}^{n^{1/k}} \lfloor x^k \rfloor \, dx = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} m\left((m+1)^{1/k} - m^{1/k}\right),$$ which is exactly what we established in the fifth line of the main computation shown in my original answer.  Remember that the whole purpose of partitioning the interval of integration is to select those subintervals for which the integrand $\lfloor x^k \rfloor$ is *constant* within each subinterval, thus turning the integral into a sum.  There is no need to calculate an antiderivative of the expression $x^k$.

Comment: @FdstZfsy See the edit to my answer above.

Comment: @FdstZfsy No apologies needed.  See second edit to my answer above.

Comment: I don't really know how to thank you. I am ashamed, as because I am not so tech-savvy or you might call me technologically challenged(!) for, I made so many mistakes while typing on and on. I resolved those errors without taking prior permissions that whether it's legal in this site or not. But I still did it, for I was feeling highly abashed or uncomfortable if you say, to hover over here and find myself making nonsensical errors and then apologising to others. I feel sorry even for my misery. But now, I checked my post for 26 minutes and edited it, and added a bit of my continuation

Comment: work as well. Your solution is elegant. But I dont know the loophole in my (nonsensical calculations as you may feel) calculations. I am stuck in this last step...

Comment: Just to let you know, I already accepted your answer and couldn't resist myself from upboting and thanking all your travails to cope up with this stupidity(, if you say so ) of mine.

Comment: @FdstZfsy Maybe identifying the mistake was trivial to some people, but please don't call yourself stupid, because you're not. You don't have to feel bad about the mistake. The fact that you got a really good and informative answer shows that your question was worth answering.

Comment: @Accelerator Thanks a lot for your kind words!

Comment: @heropup This seems strange! I find no mistake in my (now edited post), but our answers should have been the same. There might be a bug in my solution. Any ideas?